# publish content after varification by admin

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I have created video gallery with help of cck . I have created a content type. Now My requirment is that  when user add video it should not be published to all user.When admin active that content then it should be publish.
How can i do this please suggest me if there is any module for that.I am using drupal 6.

Thanks

Comment: see also: google://"drupal unpublished by default"

Answer (score 2):

There is several modules implementing this kind of publication workflow:

- [Workflow](http://drupal.org/project/workflow)
- [Content Moderation](http://drupal.org/project/content_moderation)
- [Moderation](http://drupal.org/project/moderation)
- [Revisioning](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning)
- [Modr8](http://drupal.org/project/modr8)

I only have experience with Revisioning which was pretty easy to install and straightforward to use. Workflow seems overkill for a simple publication workflow without a lot of additional features/behaviors.

Revisioning is also the only module to have a Drupal 7 release. Speaking for Drupal 7, once you get there you have the [Workbench](http://drupal.org/project/workbench) and [Maestro](http://drupal.org/project/maestro) modules.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Workflow module](http://drupal.org/project/workflow). Mongolito404 listed some good options for a simple approval workflow.  You can also use the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) if you like.

Help/Tutorials:
[Drupal Workflow Automation](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/drupal-workflow-automation)
[How do I set up the Workflow module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1861/how-do-i-set-up-the-workflow-module)

If you choose the [Revisioning module](http://drupal.org/project/revisioning), a detailed tutorial on how to set it up can be found at http://drupal.org/node/408968

Comment: thanks. if you can provide the link for configuration for this module then it would be better

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any extra modules to do what you need to do.

Just edit your new content type and uncheck *Published* in the *Workflow settings* section. This will make all new posts of that type unpublished by default.

Then, as an adminstrator, go to the content list at /admin/content/node and set it to show only items where status is not published.

Edit the unpublished nodes individually to publish them by checking the *Publish* box under *Publishing options*.

You could even use Drupal 6's core Triggers and Actions modules to have the site send you an email whenever a new video node is created.